# Is it a good/secure way for hashing passwords PHP

Tags: php, passwords, password-protection, php-password-hash

I was using :

```
function generateHash($password) {
    if (defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH) {
        $salt = '$2y$11$' . substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 22);
        return crypt($password, $salt);
    }
}
```

for hashing passwords but its incompatible for PHP Version lower than 5.3.7.
So I created this small function to generate and verify passwords But since I am not pro in Security I want to know if it is quite secure or is still insecure.

*My function:*

```
//$hash variable is also used to check weather we are creating or verifying passwords.
function password($password,$hash=FALSE){

    $salt=array("hfuiliffa","wiaelfbs","usfewl","fr6j5","gwg8","bs4$","fgthwv");//An array of salts
    if ($hash){
        foreach ($salt as $s1)
            foreach ($salt as $s2)
                if ($s1.sha1($s2.$password)===$hash)
                return true;

        return FALSE;//If we are still here means time to return false.
    }else {
        return $salt[array_rand($salt)].sha1($salt[array_rand($salt)].$password);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using > PHP 5.5 You can use the PHP's built-in function `password_hash`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Yes but I want my scripts work on almost all versions..

Comment: I would recommend generating random salts, as opposed to having them in an array.

Comment: I thought it would be better to hash passwords along with passwords which is not possible in case of random ones..
I mean I dont want the hash of password saved as an substring between salt(s)

Comment: [Don't roll your own crypto.](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197)

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to use the new function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). As you already know there is a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) working for PHP version 5.3.7. upwards.

If you really need to support lower PHP versions, you can replace the crypt parameter from "$2y$%02d$" to "$2a$%02d$", this generates a BCrypt hash as well. It is the best you can do with older versions. Alternatively you can have a look at the [example code](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt) at my homepage.

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7') >= 0)
  $algorithm = '$2y$%02d$'; // BCrypt, with fixed unicode problem
else
  $algorithm = '$2a$%02d$'; // BCrypt
```

If you absolutely need to support PHP 4.x there is no BCrypt support, in this case i would recommend to use the [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) library. BTW your scheme with the constant "salts" gives nearly no protection.

Comment: Thank you very much for this,I also want review for my function is it good to use it ?

Comment: @Subhanker - I'm sorry to disappoint you, but your scheme with the constant "salts" is extremely unsafe. There is so much done wrong, that i would recommend to read my tutorial abour [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) first.